# How do I access public recommendations with the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, public

I'm looking for a way to get access to public recommendations from a Facebook places page.

It does not appear that the Graph API allows access to this.  Does anybody know of another way?

Comment: Signature is removed, Please refer the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Using the graph you can run FQL statements.  Try running something against the checkins table  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/